# How to return a dynamic struct array from a function in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am having issues figuring out the syntax for returning a dynamic struct array from a function. I have the following small example:

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps

 typedef struct{
    string     Name;
    int        Age;
 } PersonType;

function  PersonType A []  getPeopleInfo();
   automatic string Name [50];//Max of 50 people
   automatic int Age [50];
   PersonType A [];
   /*Turns out we only have 3 people->this may change at runtime*/
   Name[0]="Jon";Age[0]=25;
   Name[1]="Ana";Age[1]=32;
   Name[2]="Ali";Age[2]=19;

  A=new[3];/*This size may change at runtime*/
   for(int idx=0;idx<3;idx++)
     begin
        A[idx].Name=Name[idx];
        A[idx].Age=Age[idx];
     end
   return A;
endfunction // getPeopleInfo

module Test();
   PersonType A [];
initial begin
   A=getPeopleInfo();
   for(int idx=0;idx<A.size();idx++)
     begin
        $display(A[idx].Name);
        $display(A[idx].Age);
     end

end
endmodule // Test
```

When I modify the function so that it passes the dynamic struct array as argument ie:

```
void getPeopleInfo(output PersonType A []);
```

Then it works fine. Is it possible to return a dynamic struct array from a function?, if so what is the correct syntax?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `typedef` when you want a function to return an unpacked type.

```
typedef PersonType PersonType_da_t[];

function automatic PersonType_da_t getPeopleInfo();
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked. I have a follow-up question about the "automatic". My understanding is that automatic forces variables to be in the stack (not static). But when returning a struct like the example above I am having a hard time conceptualizing what it means. Or what would be the consequences of not adding the "automatic" key word.

Comment: For your example, it does not matter, but it is a good habit to get into. Putting the "automatic" in the function header makes _all_ variables in the function automatic: the return variable, arguments and local variables. See https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/what-exact-difference-between-static-tasks/functions-and-automatic-tasks/functions-please-explain-clear-example#reply-44935